# Why is it called pushforward measure?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-fields

I'm trying to get an intuitive sense of the pushforward measure.

Let $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector field. We can define a corresponding pushforward measure: for an initial measure $\mu$, the pushforward induced by $\Phi$ would be $\nu$ such that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nu(x) f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mu(y) f(\Phi(x)) dx \;\;\;\; \text{ for any } f\in C^0_0(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
This says that $\mathbb{E}_\nu[f(x)] = \mathbb{E}_\mu [f(\Phi(x))]$.

I've also seen pushforward measure defined as: for any Borel set $B\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ \nu(\Phi^{-1}(B)) = \mu(B).$$

This says that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent measures under a transformation of the state space by $\Phi$.

- Are these definitions equivalent? If we pick $f$ to be any continuous function with support on $B \in {\mathbb{R}^n}$, I can see how the first definition implies the second.
- Is my intuitive explanation that "$\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent under a transformation of the state space" correct?
- Why is it called pushforward measure? It seems more like a "pushbackward measure" since the original meausure of $B$ is $\mu(B)$ and the resulting measure $\nu$ takes $\Phi^{-1}(B)$ as its argument.

Comment: Regarding why it’s called the pushforward, the argument may use the preimage, but the salient fact here is: you are using the given measure on the source space to define a measure on the target space. So in this sense, you are “pushing forward” from the domain to define a measure on the codomain.

Comment: Also, I think that in your second definition of a pushforward that the arguments should be switched (assuming $\mu$ is the measure on the domain).

Comment: @shoteyes do you mean it should be $\mu(\Phi^{-1}(B)) = \nu(B)$? I'm assuming $\mu$ is the measure on the codomain, and $\nu$ is the pushforward measure of $mu$ under $\Phi$.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here because the domain and codomain happen to be equal. If you have a measurable function $X\to Y$, which one of the measurable spaces has the “initial” measure?

Comment: @shoteyes I'm not sure what you mean. I'm still learning measure theory. My interpretation was that we start with the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$  and then we can define the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \nu)$ by mapping all the elements (or Borel sets) with $\Phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pushforward measures are even more generalizable than that. In general, consider a measure space $(M, \mu)$, a $\sigma$-algebra $N$, and a measurable map $f : M \to N$. Then we can define a measure on $N$ by $\nu(S) = \mu(f^{-1}(S))$.

The reason why this is known as the "push-forward" measure is that we're taking a measure on $M$ and "pushing it forward" through the map $f$ to get a measure on $N$.

Using the monotone convergence theorem, it's easy to show that for any measurable function $g : N \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $\int g d\nu = \int (f \circ g) d \mu$ (this can be done by taking an increasing sequence of simple functions $N \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, the integrals of which converge to the integral of $g$). This can easily be extended to show $\int g d\nu = \int (f \circ g) d \mu$ for any measurable $g$, with the left side being defined iff the right side is.

So the two definitions are indeed equivalent. As for whether your intuitive explanation is correct, I don't think such a thing can be correct or incorrect, only useful or not useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One quick question: if $M=N$, can we also write $f$ using the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mu/d\nu$?

Comment: And why do we not say $\nu(\Phi(A)) = \mu(A)$ for all Borel sets $A \in M$? Is this not equivalent to $\nu(B) = \mu(\Phi^{-1}(B))$ for Borel sets $B\in N$?

Comment: @900edges It is not equivalent. Consider $\Phi(x) = x^2$, then we would have $1 = \mu([0, 1]) = \nu(\Phi([0, 1])) = \nu([0, 1]) = \nu(\Phi([-1, 1])) = \mu([-1, 1]) = 2$.